# Compare strings for equality

Tags: c#, string, compare, string-comparison

I want to compare a collection of strings and return the the equal parts until a not equal part occurs. (and remove traling whitespace).

example:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>
{
    "string xyz stop",
    "string abc stop",
    "string   qrt stop"
};

string result = GetEqualName(strList); // This should return "string"
```

I made the following method that works

```
string GetEqualName(IEnumerable<string> strList)
{
    string outString = "";
    bool firstTime = true;
    foreach (var subString in strList)
    {
        if (firstTime)
        {
            outString = subString;
            firstTime = false;
        }
        else
        {
            string stringBuilder = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < outString.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (outString[i] == subString[i])
                    stringBuilder = stringBuilder + outString[i];
                else
                    break;
            }
            outString = stringBuilder;
        }
    }
    outString = outString.TrimEnd(' '); // Remove traling whitespace
    return outString;
}
```

I just feel that this is something that can be done in a few lines and I am overdoing it. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Your example appears to be comparing three strings, not two as you stated.

Comment: I don't know of any built-in functions that would reduce that to a few lines (other than "clever" uses of Linq aggregations).  If your method works (and you understand _why_ it works) then I see no compelling reason to change it.

Comment: "subString" is maybe wrong word to use. It is one of the strings in the collection.

Comment: @JonathanWood might as well make things generic :)

Comment: So you want to find the longest common substring of all strings in the list from left to right? But if it ends with a common substring it should be ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `Zip` two strings together, take the pairs that are equal, and then create a string of those characters.

```
public static string LargestCommonPrefix(string first, string second)
{
    return new string(first.Zip(second, Tuple.Create)
        .TakeWhile(pair => pair.Item1 == pair.Item2)
        .Select(pair => pair.Item1)
        .ToArray());
}
```

Once you've solved the problem for the case of combining two strings, you can easily apply it to a sequence of strings:

```
public static string LargestCommonPrefix(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    return strings.Aggregate(LargestCommonPrefix);
}
```

Comment: Nice use of Aggregate to explain concept of "handle the case for two, then extend"

Answer (score 2):

This little function does basically the same as your version, but shorter.

```
string GetEqualName(IEnumerable<string> strList)
{
    int limit = strList.Min(s => s.Length);

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < limit; i++)
    {
        if (strList.Select(s => s.Substring(0,i+1)).Distinct().Count() > 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return strList.First().Substring(0, i).Trim();
}
```

Comment: Note that this is *super* inefficient.  You're constantly doing the same work over and over and over again, in addition to the fact that there's no short circuiting in here, so you're computing all of the substrings of all of the strings of every length less than or equal to the final value.

Comment: I never said it was faster ;) In all seriousness though, the difference is pretty minimal until the strings get large. I was actually working on a faster version, but a) this was a quickly-posted answer written while waiting for a build at work, and b) when the asker's name is "I am still pretty new to this" and the question is about something as simple (on the surface at least) as comparing strings, I figured an easy-to-understand version might be appreciated. The efficient version would be to use `.TakeWhile()` or a conditional zip. Besides, it beats a `StringBuilder`!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different method which does what you want. I looks for the longest common substring from left to right using a `HashSet<string>`:

```
string GetCommonStartsWith(IEnumerable<string> strList, StringComparer comparer = null)
{
    if(!strList.Any() || strList.Any(str => string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)))
        return null;
    if(!strList.Skip(1).Any())
        return strList.First(); // only one

    if(comparer == null) comparer = StringComparer.CurrentCulture;
    int commonLength = strList.Min(str => str.Length);

    for (int length = commonLength; length > 0; length--)
    {
        HashSet<string> duptester = new HashSet<string>(comparer);
        string first = strList.First().Substring(0, length).TrimEnd();
        duptester.Add(first);
        bool allEqual = strList.Skip(1)
            .All(str => !duptester.Add(str.Substring(0, length).TrimEnd()));
        if (allEqual)
            return first;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that uses less LINQ than some of the other answers and might possibly be more performant.

```
string GetEqualName(IEnumerable<string> strList)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int minLength = strList.Min(s => s.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
    {
        char? c = null;
        foreach (var s in strList)
        {
            if (c == null)
                c = s[i];
            else if (s[i] != c)
                return builder.ToString().TrimEnd();
        }
        builder.Append(c);
    }
    return builder.ToString().TrimEnd();
}
```